# Why am I getting an unexpected endwhile?

Tags: php

```
    <?php
        $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => -1)); 
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $special_notes = $custom["special_notes"][0];
        $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
        $view_more = $custom["view_more"][0];
    ?>

    <article class="project">
        <section class="thumbnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <section class="description">
                <hgroup>
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <h3>
                        <?php
                        $terms_as_text = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'Skills', '', ', ', '' ) ;
                        echo strip_tags($terms_as_text);
                        ?>
                    </h3>
                </hgroup>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <p class="star"><?=$special_notes?></p>
                <span>
                    <?php if (!empty($website_url)) { echo 'Launch <a href="' . $website_url . '" target="_blank">Website<a>' ?> | Read <a href="<?=$view_more?>" target="_blank">more</a> about this project
                </span>
            </section>
        </section>
    </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

</section>
```

I get an unexpected endwhile on line 35. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Missing `}` on line 29, is my guess.

Comment: Thanks, I added in the missing bracket. However, something else must be wrong since the html comes out wrong. Here is my updated code. Do you see anything wrong in it? http://pastebin.com/TrawVzxB

Comment: I suggest you edit your question (or open another) and include the expected output and the actual output, along with your code.

Comment: Code in pastebin will disappear after a while.  Put code directly in your question so its saved for future generations of SOers.

Answer (score 0):

Mismatched brace on line 29; you don't close your if's {.